# Regex - check string has one or more chars without some chars

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string like that

```
const str = "<p><p><br></p>something</p>";
```

I want to check if the string has one or more char without `<, >, p, /, b, r, (whitespace)`. In the above case it should true, because the string has char of `s, o, m, e` e.t.c

How can do this check ?

Comment: What should be the result for `<p>p</p>`? Also, [beware Zalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/240443).

Comment: Is `[^<>/pbr\s]` what you want?

Comment: Remove all tags
    <.*?>

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the text from html and check like below:

```js
    

    function extractContent(s) {
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = s;
      return span.textContent || span.innerText;
    };
        
    cont = extractContent("<p><p><br></p>something</p>");
    if(cont)
      console.log(cont, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use lookaround in regex.

> Lookahead and lookbehind, collectively called “lookaround”, are zero-length assertions just like the start and end of line, and start and end of word anchors.

**Example.**

```js
  let regex = /(?<!<)[\w](?!>)/g;
const str = "<p><p><br></p>something</p>";

if(regex.test(str)) {
  console.log('Yes');
} else {
  console.log('No');
}
console.log('Match: ', str.match(regex).toString());
```

OR just use simple `Character ranges`.

```js
    let regex = /[^pbr<>\/]/g;
    const str = "<p><p><br></p>something</p>";
    if(regex.test(str)) {
      console.log('Yes');
    } else {
      console.log('No');
    }
    console.log("Match: ", str.match(regex).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out with lodash's `pullAllBy` function

```
let arr = "<p><p><br></p>somebbthing</p>"

const s1 = arr.split('');

let newArr = _.pullAllBy(s1, ['<', '>', '/', 'p', 'b', 'r']);
if(newArr.length > 0) {
  console.log('true');
}
```